# Load zip files from FDA web into python

Tags: python, excel, url, load

so at this link https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/cder/ndcxls.zip
there is a zip folder with 2 xls files, product and package.
I try to load them into python and convert into panda types.
but pd.read_excel returns this error message
"
XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'PRODUCTI'"

I tried to manually download and extract two files. excel does pop up some warning message but seems not impact usage enventually.

is there a way I can walk around this error message and load two files into python?

thanks

show me the code to successfully load zip files into python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... It turns out the two `.xls` files are tab-delimited. Yet this doesn't seem to work:

```py
pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='\t')
```

The file is not encoded in `utf-8`. Instead it supports `latin1`, `ISO-8859-1`, and `'cp1252'`.

I finally get the file loaded with:

```py
pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='\t', encoding='latin1')
```